# how do i get choices value of django forms in templates

Tags: python, django, templates

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='gender', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)


  GENDER_CHOICES = (
(0,'Male'),
(1,'Female'),
(2,'Not to disclose'),
)
```

how do i use choices values in templates like following codes in django templates

```
        {% for field in form %}
        {% ifequal field.name 'gender' %}
         <select id="{{ field.label_for_id }}" name="{{ field.name }}" class='form-control'>
        {% for choice in field.choices %}
          <option value="{{ choice.0 }}">{{ choice.1 }]</option>
        {% endfor %}
          </select>
          {% endifequal %}
```

and is there any recommanded sites which arrange variable names for django templates?

it is so difficult to find correct name or built in function which are rendered in templates

Comment: Your question seems to provide already an answer to the question?

Comment: but it doesn't work Intuitively .. there is no option in select box

Comment: What's wrong with letting the form field render itself ???  https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: try to use `field.field.widget.choices` instead of `field.choices` in for loop of your html template